# groovy html template ' yieldUnescaped ' is ignored in ratpack

Tags: groovy, ratpack

I am trying to inject a partial html into [GTPL file](http://www.groovy-lang.org/templating.html), but it seems always "escapes" html content. How can send HTML snippet to markup and render it directly?

Contents of "hello.gtpl"

```
yieldUnescaped '<!DOCTYPE html>'
html {
    yieldUnescaped text
}
```

From ratpack.groovy

```
    get('helloplain') { //works .but clumsy
        String htmlPayLoad = "<!DOCTYPE html>  <html>  <title> Hello </title><body> <h3> Hello </h3> </body> </html>"
        context.getResponse().contentType(HttpHeaderConstants.HTML_UTF_8).send(htmlPayLoad.getBytes());
    }
    get('hellotemplate') { //ex: /users/
        String text = "<title> Hello </title><body> <h3> Hello </h3> </body> "
        render groovyMarkupTemplate( "hello.gtpl"  ,text: text  )
    }
```

`localhost:5050/helloplain`  delivers a proper HTML where as  `localhost:5050/hellotemplate` delivers a file that has escaped all HTML content.

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html>&lt;title&gt; Hello &lt;/title&gt;&lt;body&gt; &lt;h3&gt; Hello &lt;/h3&gt; &lt;/body&gt; </html>
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to configure the `MarkupTemplateEngine` in order to disable auto escaping.
Here's a working example using latest stable version of Ratpack.

ratpack.groovy

```
@Grab('io.ratpack:ratpack-groovy:1.1.1')

import static ratpack.groovy.Groovy.ratpack
import static ratpack.groovy.Groovy.groovyMarkupTemplate
import ratpack.groovy.template.MarkupTemplateModule

ratpack {
  bindings {
    module(MarkupTemplateModule) { config ->
      config.autoEscape = false
    }
   }

  handlers {
    get {
      String text = '<title>Hello</title><body><h3>Hello</h3></body>'
      render groovyMarkupTemplate('hello.gtpl', text: text)
    }
  }
}
```

templates/hello.gtpl

```
yieldUnescaped '<!DOCTYPE html>'

html {
  yieldUnescaped text
}
```

Output of curl against running app

```
$ curl localhost:5050
<!DOCTYPE html><html><title>Hello</title><body><h3>Hello</h3></body></html>
```

For a list of which attributes are available for configuration you can check the GDK http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/text/markup/TemplateConfiguration.html

Comment: That affects all requests, correct? Is there a way to restrict select requests?

Comment: @Jayan this should only help `yieldUnescaped` to unescape HTML entities and characters, all other `yield` ing of text should still escape any HTML entities.

Comment: Alright.. Accepting the answer, will grant bounty when that is eligible.